# Colspan are the same but does not look the same in browser

Tags: asp.net, html

The colspan is the same but does not look the same when I run the program and view it in the browser,  Why is that? One is a little bit longer than the other. Parent/Guardian Information is longer than the Student Information..Thanks for your Help

```
 <td class="tblHead"  colspan="6">Student Information</td>

<td class="tblHead" colspan="6"> Parent/Guardian Information</td>



   <asp:Panel ID="panelADD" runat="server">
    <table style="width:100%; text-align:left;">
    <tr>
        <td class="tblHead"  colspan="6">Student Information<uc2:PopupCertify ID="ucPopupCertify"        runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>



 <table style="width:100%; text-align:left;">
      <tr>
       <td class="tblHead" colspan="6"> Parent/Guardian Information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Comment: Can't tell without the full HTML. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: You'll have to show more than this maybe a screenshot of how it's showing up.

Comment: If the example has your full HTML in there, then it will have problems because you didn't end the first table, or you need to take out the second table definition if they should be part of the same table. If you posted snippets, indicate as such.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this markup. Make sure your open and closing tags match up and that your elements are nested correctly.

Comment: You at least need to post the entire markup for the table.

Comment: I second @shiznit123 post a **complete** section showing only the problematic piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colspan doesn't set the width. It simply says this cell spans X number of columns. So in your case you are creating a single cell that spans 6 columns. Since the width of the columns spanned could be different, then the width of the cells will be different.

Since currently there is only one row, with a single cell in that row (that spans 6 columns), the cell width will be the same size as its contents. So, because the text "Parent/Guardian Information" is longer than "Student Information" its cell will be longer to accommodate it.

To make these cells the same size, you should update your CSS Class tblHead to include a width:

```
<style>
.tblHead {
  width: 350px;
  /* Your other style information */
}
</style>
```